# How exactly does php mysqli_query work with mysqli_fetch_array and named indexes?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am a little curios about two things, first, how exactly does mysqli_query work and second, how exactly does it work with mysqli_fetch_array? I understand the basics, and know how to make it work, but I was hoping to get a more advanced explanation on how it works. My professor has shown us how to use it and we have recently used a stament like the one below, but I am wondering, how does it send the information into the $result_book? Does it use a "\n" for each row? How does fetch know one row from the other? Is it some sort of array or two dimensional array that is returned?

Also, how does the array index by name work? I am curious how it knows to have an index, because I thought it would all just be text, and you would have to parse it out like in java reading from a txt file, but it knows how to break things up with stuff like $row['title']. Do we even need the word title? or can we just use integer values for the index?

This is much more complex than the basic stuff I have been used to and just curious to know how it works on a somewhat deeper level.

Here is the query statment

```
    $sql_book = "SELECT title, type ";
    $sql_book .= " FROM book ";
    $sql_book .= " Group by title, type ";
    $result_book =  mysqli_query($db, $sql_book);
```

and this is the fetch statement in the loop

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_book);

        $title = $row['title'];
        $type  = $row['type'];
```

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code.

Comment: If this is about "How does it communicate with the server" then see [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/binary-protocol-value.html).

Comment: @tadman I think OP is asking about a textual protocol instead. So the following link is more relevant: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/com-query-response.html#packet-COM_QUERY_Response

Comment: That's actually a good question and I doubt it worth a closure. The only quirk, there are too much questions in one, which indeed can be qualified as off topic. The question would benefit from the edit that would focus on one certain question.

Comment: In short, there is never a "text". You are yet to learn about *binary* protocols. To put it very simply, it's doesn't separate the data by delimiters, such as "\n" but rather by the length, like, "here goes another field, it lasts 100 bytes". So PHP reads the next 100 bytes and puts them in the array element. As of the indices, there is another binary packet that has all the names in order. So PHP can assign the first field name to the first column and so on. And yes, using numeric indices is possible you can read on it on the manual page

Comment: @YourCommonSense one of neds more focus clise reasons is asking multiple questions in a single post, so I disagree with your assessment that this is a good question and should not have been closed!

Comment: @yourCommonSense FYI this question has been reopened.

Comment: @Dharman I am in doubts. The OP didn't show up, neither with an edited question nor with any feedback to clarify their inquiry. Looks like the answer would serve noone and hence the question better was left closed.